# How to change TextInput styles without affecting previous typed text react native

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, textinput, richtext

I am trying to create rich text editor that will have options like click to bold how can i achieve this without affecting previous content when i attempt to change them from state it ends up affecting previous inserted text`

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
          constructor(props){
               super(props)
               this.state={
                      text:'',
                      inputStyles:{
                            fontWeight:'light'
                      }
               }
          }
        _Bold =()=>{
            this.setState({inputStyles:{
                  fontWeight:'bold'
            }})

        }

      render() {
        return(


               <View style={styles.container}>
                       <StatusBar backgroundColor="#24292e" barStyle="light-content" />

                       <TextInput  placeholder="Star to write"
                        style={this.state.inputStyles}
                      />

              <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>this._Bold()}>
                    <Text>BOLD</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
               </View>



               ) 
          }
      }
    `
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, I think you have to change your `TextInput` as following:

```
  <TextInput 
    placeholder="Star to write"
    value={this.state.text}
    onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({text)}
    style={this.state.inputStyles}
  />
```

The problem is that you are not storing the text into the state, once it gets rendered it gets lost

Comment: let me try this and see

Comment: That's correct. When you define value={this.state.text}, the textInput will show the written text from before.